# Series, computing the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+2+\cdots+n}{n^3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

How to compute the following limit? The series is given by

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}(1+2+\cdots+n)$$

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Do you know a formula for the sum $1+2+\cdots+n$?

Comment: Hint: $1+2+\cdots+n\leqslant n+n+\cdots+n=n^2$.

Comment: This is not a series, it is a sequence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for fun:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{n}+\frac{2}{n}\frac{1}{n}+\ldots+\frac{n}{n}\frac{1}{n}\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\times\int_{0}^{1}\text{d}x=0$$

Comment: Did you just edit that??  (I'm feeling like I was seeing things...)

Comment: What did you see?

Comment: Thanks, could I ask you for the explanation of the part containing the integral?

Comment: @RGB I saw $\lim \cdots = 1$

Comment: I saw $2$ instead of $3$ too. Weird things are going on here. Haunted question.

Comment: @justik It is a joke. Just a convoluted way of proving it. If you take the definition of the integral of the constant function $1$ using Riemann sums and take uniform partitions of $n$ steps you get what is inside the brackets.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation :-) I studied this part of math years ago :-). Finally, I remember the formula for sum (1 +...+n) and got the solution, analogous to the next post...

Answer (score 2):

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+2+...+n}{n^{3}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}{n^{3}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2n}\big(1+\frac{1}{n}{}\big)=0$

Answer (score -2):

$1 + \cdots + n = n(n+1)/2$ and hence

$$ \frac{1}{n^{3}}(n(n+1))/2 = \frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{2n^{2}} $$

and this goes to zero.

Comment: Corrected the error!